# Using Web Deploy - Permissions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, web-deployment, webdeploy

I am using Web Deploy to deploy my MVC3 applications from Visual Studio 2010.

All goes perfect when I user the `Administrator` account of the server in the Web Deploy dialog.

I have a new employee starting. I created a new user on the server. This way, I can disable this user if necessary. I gave `Administrator` permissions as a test, but sadly this user was not allowed to deploy to the server.

Can anyone tell me what (minimum) permissions I need to give this user so they can deploy applications from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you ever solved your problem, but I had the same problem today. Reading this article helped me solve it. See #5 in the [article](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2011/04/05/announcing-web-deploy-2-0-refresh.aspx) for setting up specific user permissions for Web Deploy.

Answer (score 1):

If your target machine is running IIS6 or a client version of Windows (Vista/7) then they need to have administrative privileges.  Using the Web Deployment Agent should work for this (e.g. publish to `http://foobar`).

If you want to allow non-admins to publish, you need a machine running IIS7 on a server SKU of Windows (2008/2008R2).  You can set up delegation rules to allow users permissions to specific WebDeploy providers.  See [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/516/configure-the-web-deployment-handler/) for a description of how to get started.  This goes through the Web Deploy Management Service, so your target machine will be either `https://foobar:8172/MSDeploy.axd`, or just `foobar`).

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me what (minimum) permissions I need to give this user so they can deploy applications from Visual Studio?

Only users with administrative privileges are allowed to modify the server settings, creating web sites, virtual directories, etc... which is what the Web Deploy does.

Comment: Hello, I did make my new user a member of the Administrators group however this did not work. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks Paul